# opencl:how many shared variables are allocated when using __local

Tags: opencl

Suppose we have declared as this as a kernel parameter:

```
__local float *sharedData
```

And let us say the work group size is 512. Then how many such copies of sharedData will be allocated ? 512 ? or there will be only one copy, and will be broadcasted to all the threads?

What about the other variables in the kernel. My understanding is all the variables in the kernel body will be duplicated 'n' no. of time , where 'n' is the no. of threads in the work group.

Comment: Local variables exist once per workgroup. Default (private) variables exist once per work item.

Comment: @DarkZeros so you mean there would be a single value in shared memory , and will be read by all the threads, (by broadcast?) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the local array is visible (you say broadcast) to all work items in the workgroup.  There will be one copy per workgroup regardless of the workgroup size.

If your workgroup is 512 workitems and you want one float per work item, then `sharedData` will have 512 elements, and it's up to you to specify this size via [clSetKernelArg](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html).

As DarkZeros says, private variables are specific to each *workitem*.  Each of the 512 workitems has its own copy.

(Note: I think what you're calling a *thread* is what we call a *workitem*.)

Comment: @user3891236 A thread is something independent, that runs on its own. While a Workitem is a OpenCL specific term, and reffers to the small pieces inside a work group. They are not threads, since they are not independent, all of them run the same code with different data.

Comment: @DarkZeros Thanks for the info. Can you point me to some reference in support of your argument (especially that workitems are not independent)?

Comment: I think "thread" comes from CUDA's nomanclature and is not an OpenCL.  See this reference: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~lerner/spring12/Preso07-OpenCL.pdf  Also see slide 26 of this presentation: https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/40025977/Cuda+and+OpenCL+API+comparison_presented.pdf for a table of CUDA concepts mapped to OpenCL.